# Formatting of long equation containing a matrix?

Tags: equations, formatting, matrices

I've a problem formatting this equation. It's containing a 5x1 matrix and the content of a cell in a matrix is pretty long. All in all it does not fit on the page. Should I use `split()` or is there another option?

```
\begin{equation} 
\varphi_{i,j,k}^{n+1} = \varphi_{i,j,k}^{n} + \delta t \frac{1}{|x^3|}
\begin{smallmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}((\rho v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v1)_{i,j-1,k})\delta x + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_2)_{i+1,j,k}-(\rho v_2)_{i-1,j,k})\delta y + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_3)_{i,j,k+1}-(\rho v_3)_{i,j,k-1})\delta z\\
\frac{1}{2}((\rho v_1^2+p)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v_1^2+p)_{i,j-1,k})\delta x + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_1 v_2)_{i+1,j,k}-(\rho v_1 v_2)_{i-1,j,k})\delta y + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_1 v_3)_{i,j,k+1}-(\rho v_1 v_3)_{i,j,k-1})\delta z\\
\frac{1}{2}((\rho v_2 v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v_2 v_1)_{i,j-1,k})\delta x + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_2^2+p)_{i+1,j,k}-(\rho v_2^2+p)_{i-1,j,k})\delta y + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_2 v_3)_{i,j,k+1}-(\rho v_2 v_3)_{i,j,k-1})\delta z\\
\frac{1}{2}((\rho v_3 v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v_3 v_1)_{i,j-1,k})\delta x + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_3 v_2)_{i+1,j,k}-(\rho v_3 v_2)_{i-1,j,k})\delta y + \frac{1}{2}((\rho v_3^2+p)_{i,j,k+1}-(\rho v_3^2+p)_{i,j,k-1})\delta z\\
\frac{1}{2}(((\rho E+p)v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-((\rho E+p)v_1)_{i,j-1,k})\delta x + \frac{1}{2}(((\rho E+p)v_2)_{i+1,j,k}-((\rho E+p)v_2)_{i-1,j,k})\delta y + \frac{1}{2}(((\rho E+p)v_3)_{i,j,k+1}-((\rho E+p)v_3)_{i,j,k-1})\delta z\\
\end{smallmatrix} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: When things look that bad, I usually try to rethink my notation!

Comment: Yeah well, I agree you, but to rethink the notation of a equation is pretty hard. Since you cannot change an equation that much

Comment: I agree with Ian. This is hardly readable as it is. What does the expression inside the `smallmatrix` even mean.

Comment: It's the result of an finite volume method of the euler equations

Comment: factorize as much as you can. Get `\frac{1}{2}` out of there, do a scalar product with the vector `(dx, dy, dz)` (just examples) and then start introducing variables for each matrix cell. `\begin{smallmatrix}A\\BC\\D\\E\end{smallmatrix}` where `A=((\rho v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v1)_{i,j-1,k})...`

Comment: If you need the whole thing, put everything in a `scalebox` from `graphicx` or rotate it on a landscape page. However, your reader will not thank you for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\varphi_{i,j,k}^{n+1} = \varphi_{i,j,k}^{n} + \delta t \frac{1}{|x^3|}\mathbf{A}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{B}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\partial x\\\partial y\\\partial z
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{B}= \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
a &= (\rho v_1)_{i,j+1,k}-(\rho v_1)_{i,j-1,k}\\
b &= (\rho v_2)_{i+1,j,k}-(\rho v_2)_{i-1,j,k}\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}\dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: haven't checked the math on that... But you get the idea.

Comment: The math is correct.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I put one underline to the first `v_1`. A typo you should get rid of before book release. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Nice refactoring. I'd consider inserting B from (3) into (2), or even folding (2) and (3) into (1), keeping just the definitions of a, b, ... separate. OP's choice.

Comment: FYI, it has to be a 5X3 matrix. Thanks anyway